# Count unique values of consts

Tags: unique, z3, counting, smt

In my project I defined following consts:

```
(declare-const v0_g Int)
(declare-const v1_g Int)
(declare-const v2_g Int)
(declare-const v3_g Int)
(declare-const v4_g Int)
...
```

In result, I got following values in my model:

```
...    
(define-fun v4_g () Int
2)
(define-fun v3_g () Int
10)
(define-fun v2_g () Int
10)
(define-fun v1_g () Int
8)
(define-fun v0_g () Int
0)
...
```

Now I want to define new const called `cost` and assign the number of unique values of `vi_g` (in the example above `cost == 4` (i.e. `{0,2,8,10}`). How can I achieve it using z3 solver?

The only idea I came up with is:

1. Knowing the maximum value (`MAXVAL`) that can be assigned to any of `vi_g`, define `MAXVAL` boolean consts (`ci`),
2. For each of this consts make an assert that e.g. `c0 = (v0_g == 0) v (v1_g == 0) v ... v (vn_g == 0)`,
3. Count how many `ci` const equals `True`.

However, it requires a lot of additional clauses if `MAXVAL` is large.

Comment: Are you trying to minimize this cost in some way? If not, the easiest to compute this value would be to simply do it outside of z3, in the environment you call z3 from.

Comment: @LeventErkok: yes, I'd like to minimize this cost.

Comment: @downvoter: what is wrong with this question?

Comment: One idea would be to put all the `vi_g`'s into a set of integers, use the `set-has-size` predicate to grab the size of that set, and then minimize it. `set-has-size` is a relatively new addition to Z3 (so you'll probably have to build from github sources or use a nightly build), but that might do the trick.

Comment: @LeventErkok: how can I use it directly in Z3 (without API)?

Comment: It'd be something like this: https://gist.github.com/LeventErkok/e08a65ac190da3ba88a2989a146a407e But experimenting with z3, it doesn't seem to give correct answers. `set-has-size` is pretty new, so likely there are some bugs. If you dive into it and distill what looks like a bug, you should report it at z3 github site!

Comment: @LeventErkok: thanks, I will dive into it.

Comment: Looks like the optimizer is not working with `set-has-size`. One idea would be to simply use `set-has-size` to extract the value of the set, and call z3 repeatedly with new constraints to lower this value until you get `unsat`. That way you don't need the optimizer, and can hopefully converge on a minimum within a reasonable number of iterations.

Answer (score -1):

There's no easy way to count the number of models of a general formula. Either your specific formula allows some sort of simplification or it isn't easy. See e.g. literature for #SAT (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-SAT).
A naïve way is to implement the counting with a linear loop blocking one model at a time (or potentially several ones if the model is partial).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I understand correclty, you referred to a different problem from the one I tried to resolve.

Comment: Yes, I think @nuno-lopes misunderstood the question. A possible solution is to use a sorting network to sort the values of all `vi_g`, such that you can use a linear number of comparisons between network outputs to count the number of occurrences of each of them.